# How to add an if statement before calculation in AWK

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a series of files that I am looping through and calculating the mean on a column within each file after performing a serious of filters. Each filter is piped in to the next, BEFORE calculating the mean on the final output. All of this is done within a sub shell to assign it to a variable for later use.

for example:

`variable=$(filter1 | filter 2 | filter 3 | calculate mean)`

to calculate the mean I use the following code

`... | awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$5;}END{print s/NR;}'`

So, my problem is that depending on the file, the number of rows after the final filter is reduced to 0, i.e. the pipe passes nothing to AWK and I end up with `awk: fatal: division by zero attempted` printed to screen, and the variable then remains empty. I later print the variable to file and in this case I end up with BLANK in a text file.  Instead what I am attempting to do is state that if NR==0 then assign 0 to the variable so that my final output in the text file is 0.

To do this I have tried to add an if statement at the start of my awk command

`... | awk '{if (NR==0) print 0}BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$5;}END{print s/NR;}'`

but this doesn't change the output/ error and I am left with BLANKs

I did move the begin statement but this caused other errors (syntax and output errors)

Expected results:

given that column from a file has 5 lines and looks thus, I would filter on apple and pipe into the calculation

```
apple 10
apple 10
apple 10
apple 10
apple 10
```

code:

```
vairable=$(awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"; if($1 ~ /apple/) print $0}' file.in | awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$5;}END{print s/NR;}')
```

then I would expect the variable to be set to 10 (10*5/5 = 10)

In the following scenario where I filter on banana

```
vairable=$(awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"; if($1 ~ /banana/) print $0}' file.in | awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$5;}END{print s/NR;}')
```

given that the pipe passes nothing to AWK  I would want the variable to be 0

is it just easier to accept the blank space and change it later when printed to file - i.e. replace `BLANK` with 0?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do nor what you were hoping the modified script you posted would do (think about it - NR is the number of lines read so far so how can it ever be zero outside of the BEGIN section?). Please [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input (a couple of small files) and expected output.

Comment: of course, will do now

Comment: Given your posted sample input (1 file of 6 identical input lines) a script like `awk '{print $2; exit}'` would produce your expected output of `10` but I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for. Come up with and post a [mcve] that adequately demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a variable which you treat as a number in AWK is `0`, so you don't need `BEGIN {s=0}`.

You should put the condition in the `END` block. `NR` is not the *number of all rows*, but the *index of the current row*. So it will only give the number of rows there were at the end.

```
awk '{s += $5} END { if (NR == 0) { print 0 } else { print s/NR } }'
```

Or, using a ternary:

```
awk '{s += $5} END { print (NR == 0) ? 0 : s/NR }'
```

Also, a side note about your `BEGIN{OFS='\t'} ($1 ~ /banana/) { print $0 }` examples: most of that code is unnecessary. You can just pass the condition:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~ /banana/'`
```

When an awk program is only a condition, it uses that as a condition for whether or not to print a line. So you can use conditions as a quick way to filter through the text.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write:

```
awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"; if($1 ~ /banana/) print $0}' file.in | awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$5;}END{print s/NR;}'
```

is (assuming a regexp comparison for $1 really is appropriate, which it probably isn't):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1 ~ /banana/{ s+=$5; c++ } END{print (c ? s/c : 0)}' file.in
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Or are you trying to get the mean per column 1 like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} { s[$1]+=$5; c[$1]++ } END{ for (k in s) print k, s[k]/c[k] }' file.in
```

or something else?